# Is there any way I can run two MVC4 project in same development server port?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two MVC4 projects and my requirement is that both projects run in same development server port or same hosting. Please help.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if "same hosting" means something that is not covered in my answer.

Comment: I have two project p1 and p2, now my requirement is p1 project has a link which is target to p2 project and both project url is always same, only controller and action name will be change.

Comment: Have you thought that things like TempData or Session will be independent in each application?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can run it.

Go to project > settings > change the port.

Remember that multiple project can used same port but can't be executed at same time. When one of your project executed then port goes unavailable for every other application.

You can set same port for multiple project but only one project can execute and use that port at once.

[image]

Comment: I have two project p1 and p2, now my requirement is p1 project has a link which is target to p2 project and both project url is always same, only controller and action name will be change.

Comment: Do one of them goes in subdomain orinside directory of another project ? I simply suggest you to use a variable in web.config and use them as part of your settings. You can modify the web.config code whenever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into MVC areas? That might be cleaner, depending on your requirements. They allow you to ligically partition your application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx